# Cannot read property 'description' of undefined in angularJs

Tags: angularjs

I am getting customer details object from server in the following way,

[image]

and i want to assign the value of the 'caste' description to the model. But i am getting the error saying: **Cannot read property 'description' of undefined**

I have 'caste' details object in the following way,

```
//default object
$scope.personalDetailsObj = {
      "personalDetails": {        
        "title":"",
        "name":"",
        "fistNm":"",
        "lastNm":"",
        "caste":null
      }
    }

    $scope.casteList =  [
               {
                  "code": "0",
                  "description": "NOT APPLICABLE"
               },

               {
                  "code": "1",
                  "description": "SHARE CROPPERS"

               }
            ]

    $scope.personalDetailsObj.personalDetails = $scope.customerData.personalDetails; 

    $scope.personalDetailsObj.personalDetails.caste = $scope.casteList.filter(function(obj){return obj.code == $scope.personalDetailsObj.personalDetails.caste;})[0].description;
```

i am trying to assign the model value,

```
<input type="text" data-ng-model="personalDetailsObj.personalDetails.caste" name="caste"/>
```

Comment: Looks like `personalDetailsObj` should be `personalDetails`.

Comment: can u please check the updated one

Comment: Alright I see now. But the filter seems like it's comparing the wrong things, I don't see where this condition `return obj.code == $scope.personalDetailsObj.personalDetails.caste` would be true (comparing `caste` to `code`). And hence lead to your error. Looks like you might mean `$scope.personalDetailsObj.personalDetails.code` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are filtering the array based on this condition:

```
 obj.code == $scope.personalDetailsObj.personalDetails.caste
```

I'm not sure about your application logic, but I can see `caste` is a string, and you are trying to check it against a code. As that always return an empty array, `list[0]` will return undefined, so it can't access to the `description` property.

Maybe change it to:

```
 obj.code == $scope.personalDetailsObj.personalDetails.code
```

Or

```
 obj.caste == $scope.personalDetailsObj.personalDetails.caste
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your comparison is wrong. it should be

$scope.personalDetailsObj.personalDetails.caste = $scope.casteList.filter(function(obj){return obj.code == $scope.personalDetailsObj.personalDetails.**code**;})[0].description;